# Question about lognormal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have the following question. I'm not understanding it. Someone have any idea?

Suppose a gross return (1+R) is lognormal(0, 0.04). Find the prob-
ability that the net return R is less than 5%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}[R\leq 0.05]=\mathbb{P}[(1+R)\leq 1.05]$$

As $(1+R)\sim$ lognormal the probability can be calculated using the usual Z table

Comment: So the lognormal is just shifting by 1.

Comment: @Florent : just calculate the probability of $log(1+R)< log 1.05$ which is Gaussian distributed

Comment: thank you. got it.